# How do I import this toast component to my button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm new to Next.js and React in general. I have a button that executes an external JavaScript file (`query.js`), when it's done I want to show a toast confirming whether it's a success or failure. I got a nice-looking toast message from this [repository](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/react-notification-alert) but I have no idea how to integrate it.

Here is my `index.js` file

```
import {proses} from '../public/static/query.js'
import Notifications from './Notifications'
import useSWR from 'swr'

const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(res => res.json())
function Profile() {
  const { data, error } = useSWR('a link here', fetcher)

  if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
  if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>

  return data
}

export default function Home() {

  //fetching data
let data = Profile();
  return (
    //some code

        <button className={styles2.btnNormal} onClick={(e) => {
                                                                let result = proses(data)
                                                                if(result=="Copied to Clipboard!"){
                                                                  <Notifications /> 
                                                                  console.log("copied to clipboard!")
                                                                } else {
                                                                  console.log("not found")
                                                                }
                                                                }}>Process</button>
        
    
    //another code
  )
}
```

Here is the `Notifications.js`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NotificationAlert from 'react-notification-alert';

var options = {};
options = {
    place: 'tc',
    message: (
        <div>
            Copied to Clipboard!
        </div>
    ),
    type: "success",
    icon: "now-ui-icons ui-1_bell-53",
    autoDismiss: 1.25
}

class Notifications extends Component {
    myFunc(){
        this.refs.notify.notificationAlert(options);
    }  
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NotificationAlert ref="notify" zIndex={9999} onClick={() => {}} />
                <button onClick={() => this.myFunc()}>Hey</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Notifications;
```

Here is my external .js file (`query.js`).

```
export function proses(data) {
    //I named it data but it is actually closer to a database. I saved a list of items in google sheet. I want to lookup an item based on user input in the list and I want to do it fully on client side because it's extremely fast.
    //some client side data processing to lookup data
    //by the time this function executed the data should already fetched
    //the function will return a string "Copied to Clipboard!" if it found a match or "not found" if it doesn't
};
```

Essentially, I don't know how to modify `Notifications.js` to only call the toast and not the button example inside it.

Comment: How do you know when your external script is done, does the `proses` function return anything?

Comment: @juliomalves it returns a string

Answer (score 0):

Performing an action as/on a result of an asynchronous function (all api requests and database queries) will be done through callbacks, promises, or `async await`. Without seeing how you are "looking up" the data, it's hard to say which one you will use, but here is an example for callbacks.

### callback

```js
function process(data, callback) {
// Format data into a useable query string
  callbackStyleQuery(queryString, (err, result) => {
    If (err) {
      callback(err);
    } else {
       callback(null, result)
    }
})};
```

Then inside of your click handler you would put

```js
(e)=>{process(data, (err, result) => {
  If (err) {
    // handle appropriately
  } else {
    // do whatever you want with the result.   
  }
})
```

Forgive anything wonky about layout. I typed this on my phone.

Comment: thanks for the pointer! I added the code where I fetch the data, by the time query.js is executed, it's not exactly asynchronous. do you mind taking a look? I still don't know how to modify the toast component. I don't even know where to begin.